# Log4j (SLF4J) MDC Context in Struts 2 Interceptor

Tags: filter, struts2, slf4j, log4j2, struts2-interceptors

I find that one can set the Log4j (SL4J) MDC context in a **thread safe way** in a general filter (Code from [Adding user info to log entries in a multi-user app using Mapped Diagnostic Context](http://blog.trifork.com/2013/06/06/adding-user-info-to-log-entries-in-a-multi-user-app-using-mapped-diagnostic-context/))

```
import org.slf4j.MDC;
import javax.servlet.*;
import java.io.IOException;
 
public class MDCFilter implements Filter {
 
  @Override
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp, FilterChain chain)
          throws IOException, ServletException {
      User user= (User) session.getAttribute("USerSession");
      MDC.put("userName", user.getUserName() );
    try {
      chain.doFilter(req, resp);
    } finally {
        MDC.remove("userName");
    }
  }
 
}
```

Can I do the same approach in the Struts 2 interceptor ?! What I wonder is thread safty issues.

Struts 2 interceptor and servlet filters are not both thread safe and `MDC` implementation is thread safe, so if above code works fine in a filter, theoretically it must be work thread safe in the interceptor.

Any comments ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interceptors are not thread safe means that you have to write them in thread safe manner. For example below interceptor is thread safe.

```java
public class LoggerInterceptor extends AbstractInterceptor {
  @Override
  public String intercept(ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception {
    HttpSession session = ServletActionContext.getRequest().getSession();
    User user= (User) session.getAttribute("USerSession");
    MDC.put("userName", user.getUserName() );
    String result;
    try {
      result = invocation.invoke();
    } finally {
      MDC.remove("userName");
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```